# Merging two or more arrays by identical key numbers

Tags: php, arrays

I have 3 arrays:

```
$array1 = array (1 => 'Hello' , 2 => 'nice' 3 => 'how');
$array2 = array (1 => 'there' , 2 => 'to' 3 => 'are');
$array3 = array (1 => 'champ' , 2 => 'meet' 3 => 'you');
```

and i want to output a string that combines let's say from all the first keys of each array. 
e.g:

```
 echo "Hello there champ"
 echo "nice to meet"
```

How can i do that?
The number of values in those arrays will always be identical since these are pulled from a table.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo $array1[1] . ' ' . $array2[1] . ' ' . $array3[1]; // hello there champ 
echo $array1[2] . ' ' . $array2[2] . ' ' . $array3[2]; // nice to meet
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
function merge() {
    $arrays = func_get_args();
    $count = count($arrays[0]);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        foreach ($arrays as $array) {
            echo $array[$i];
        }

        echo "<br />";
    }
}

$array1 = array (1 => 'helo' , 2 => 'nice' 3 => 'how');
$array2 = array (1 => 'there' , 2 => 'to' 3 => 'are');
$array3 = array (1 => 'champ' , 2 => 'meet' 3 => 'you');

merge($array1, $array2, $array3);
```

Output:

```
hello there champ<br />nice to meet<br />how are you<br />
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 0 on line 8, output:helotherechamp
nicetomeet